Are Action Handles safe to share between threads?
I'm trying to understand the rclcpp example for a simple action server, specifically this line std::thread{execute, goal_handle}.detach();
The std::shared_ptr<GoalHandleFibonacci> goal_handle appears to be shared between the ros spin  thread and the spawned std::thread   which should be UB, unless the GoalHandleFibonacci  is threadsafe.   Are all the methods on an action handle thread-safe?
I can't find  any mention of thread-safety in the documentation but maybe it is and I'm not seeing it, I'm just trying to understand what is allow and not allowed.
(edited)
